# How do I get all the xtick labels?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How do I get the x-axis to show all years and months? Attached is an image of the visual I generated. I would probably have to rotate and shrink the fontsize later.

```
df_estimated_months = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])['Estimated_fire_area'].mean()

plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
df_estimated_months.plot(kind='line', title='Mean Estimated Fire Area over Time')
plt.xlabel('Year, Month')
plt.ylabel('Average Estimated Fire Area (km²)')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

I tried `plt.xticks(df_estimated_months.index.values)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your index to DateTime. After that, u can use locators to set your tick params. I haven't tested it there can be a few problems but u can implement it into your code. I hope it will be helpful. Also if u have any problem while testing this let me know, I'll try to do my best to fix problem.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(24, 6), sharex=True)

df_estimated_months.index = pd.to_datetime(df_estimated_months.index)
ax1.set_ylabel('Average Estimated Fire Area (km²)')
plt.xlabel('Year, Month')


date_formatter = DateFormatter("%Y - %b")
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1)) #Change interval depends on your dataframe
ax1.plot(df_estimated_months.index, {set your y tick}. label=name, marker='o', markersize=2)

plt.xticks(rotation=45) #Rotate
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='gray',labelsize=18,width=2)  # Set x-axis tick color to gray
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='gray',labelsize=18,width=2)  # Set y-axis tick color to gray
```